# How to define types of the auth properties in socket.io-client

Tags: typescript, socket.io

### Question

I am using socket.io-client with typescript.

When creating a socket instance, I set a token property in the auth of the Socket options, but an type error occurs when using it.

How can I resolve this?

---

- "socket.io-client": "4.5.0"
- "typescript": "4.6.4"

---

### source

```
import { io, Socket } from "socket.io-client";
import { ServerToClientEventsInterface, ClientToServerEventsInterface } from "../../../backend/socket/interface/socketEventsInterface";
const socket: Socket<ServerToClientEventsInterface, ClientToServerEventsInterface> = io({
    auth: (cb: any) => {
        cb({ token: localStorage.token })
    }
});

socket.on('created', () => {
    console.log("token", socket.auth.token);
});
```

[source capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3IJT.png)

### error

> TS2339: Property 'token' does not exist on type '{ [key: string]: any; } | ((cb: (data: object) => void) => void)'.
> Property 'token' does not exist on type '(cb: (data: object) => void) => void'.

---

the definition of Socket options

```
export interface SocketOptions {
    /**
     * the authentication payload sent when connecting to the Namespace
     */
    auth: {
        [key: string]: any;
    } | ((cb: (data: object) => void) => void);
}
```

---

### Reference document

- https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-options/#socket-options
- https://socket.io/docs/v4/middlewares/#sending-credentials

---

### tried

I've confirmed that the error can be avoided by the following method, but I don't think it's the right way to go.

```
socket.on('created', () => {
    const tmp: any = socket.auth;
    console.log("token", tmp.token);
});
```

---

let me tell you that I can't speak English well.
I'm sorry if it's a strange sentence.
Please point out any sentences that you do not understand, and I will do my best to correct them.

I would be very grateful if you could answer.
Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
import io, { Socket } from "socket.io-client";

useEffect(() => {
    console.log("starting a socket connection");
    const newSocket: Socket = io(backendURL, { query: { token: "user1" } });
    
  }, []);
```